# Return order on chained relations from cypher queries

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Let's say I have the following path in my graph:

```
user-[:NEXT]->message(n)-[:NEXT]->message(n-1)-[:NEXT]->...-[:NEXT]->message1-[:NEXT]->message0
```

In this case, can I rely on the order of returned message entities from the following query? Will it be always the same?

```
start user=node(userNode) match user-[:NEXT*]->message return message
```

And what about when `Paging` is added? Does it matter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to be 100% sure, you can use the length() function like this:

```
start user=node(userNode) match user-[r:NEXT*]->message return message order by length(r) asc;
```

this will give you the list with the shortest paths first. to get it from the end, simply use `order by length(r) desc`

Comment: thx. what are the implications of this usage regarding performance?

Comment: the implication is pretty severe as instead of pushing the results out directly as they come in cypher has to collect all data in memory, apply the sorting and return the results. With 1.9.M02 you will have a more efficient `order by ... limit x` implementation which should help you.